# The another module is throwing an unexpected and No-needed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I've created a wallet for customers where the customer will do a payment with the use of Stripe. WAnd after every transaction the customer's amount should be added to the customer's balance. To do this I've made an API in the back-end but it's not working. Here is my code backend:

**`Stripe Services`**

```
// importing required packages and modules
const { logError } = require(`../../dependencies/helpers/console.helpers`);
const { updateWalletById } = require(`../../api/controllers/wallet.controllers`);

// importing required config params
const {
  HTTP_STATUS_CODES: { SUCCESS, SERVER_ERROR }
} = require(`../../dependencies/config`);
const { STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY } = require(`../../dependencies/credentials`);

//This service method creates a new stripe payment intent and returns it
/**
 * this data service creates a new stripe payment intent
 * @async
 * @param {float} amount - the amount to be topped up
 * @param {str} currency - the currency to make payments with
 * @param {oid} walletId - the database id (object id) of the wallet to top up
 * @returns stripe payment intent's client secret
 */
const initStripePaymentIntent = async (amount, currency, walletId) => {
  try {
    // importing and initting stripe module
    const stripe = require(`stripe`)(STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY);

    // initiating stripe payment intent
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency,
      payment_method_types: [`card`],
      metadata: {
        amount,
        walletId,
        currency,
        paymentMethod: `CARD`
      }
    });

    // Update the wallet balance after the payment intent/ client secret is created
    await updateWalletById(walletId, amount);

    // returning success response to its caller
    return {
      status: SUCCESS,
      data: {
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    //This code runs in case of an error @ runtime

    // logging error messages to the console
    logError(`ERROR @ initStripePaymentIntent -> stripe.services.js`, error);

    // returning response to indicate failure
    return {
      status: SERVER_ERROR,
      error: `An unhandled exception occurred on the server.`
    };
  }
};

// exporting services as modules
module.exports = {
  initStripePaymentIntent
};
```

**`And my wallet.controllers file in which I've my updateWalletById Module:`**

```
/**
 * This controller updates specific wallets via walletId & returns it
 * @async
 * @param {obj} req - incoming request obj
 * @param {obj} res - outgoing response obj
 * @param {func} next - method to pass control to next request handler in the queue
 * @returns updated record from the database
 */
const updateWalletById = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const walletId = req.params.walletId; // Fetch walletId from request params
    const balanceToAdd = req.body.balance; // Fetch balance from request body

    // Fetch the existing wallet data
    const existingWallet = await findWalletById(walletId);
    if (existingWallet.status === NOT_FOUND) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        hasError: true,
        message: 'Wallet not found',
        error: existingWallet.error,
      });
    }

    const currentBalance = existingWallet.data.balance || 0;
    const updatedBalance = currentBalance + (balanceToAdd || 0); // Default to 0 if balanceToAdd doesn't exist

    // Update the balance in the database
    const updatedWallet = await findWalletByIdAndUpdate(
      { balance: updatedBalance }, // updateData object with the new balance value
      walletId,
      req.tokenData.sub // updater
    );

    // Check if the wallet was found
    if (updatedWallet.status === NOT_FOUND) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        hasError: true,
        message: 'Wallet not found',
        error: updatedWallet.error,
      });
    }

    return res.status(SUCCESS).json({
      hasError: false,
      message: 'Wallet updated successfully',
      data: {
        wallet: updatedWallet.data,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logError('ERROR @ updateWalletById -> wallet.controllers.js', error);

    return res.status(SERVER_ERROR).json({
      hasError: true,
      message: 'ERROR: Requested operation failed.',
      error: {
        error: 'An unexpected error occurred on the server.',
      },
    });
  }
};
```

**`Route:`**

```
// New route to update wallet balance
walletRouter.put(
  `/:walletId`,
  authenticateRequest,
  validateInput(specificWalletSchema, `PARAMS`),
  updateWalletById
);
```

**`And this is the error I'm receiving:`**

```
 2023-07-27 15:41:55 | ERROR: ERROR @ updateWalletById -> wallet.controllers.js 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'walletId')
    at updateWalletById (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/api/controllers/wallet.controllers.js:225:33)
    at initStripePaymentIntent (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/dependencies/external-services/stripe.services.js:39:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async topupViaStripe (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/api/controllers/topup.controllers.js:33:37)
 2023-07-27 15:41:55 | ERROR: ERROR @ initStripePaymentIntent -> stripe.services.js 
TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at updateWalletById (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/api/controllers/wallet.controllers.js:267:16)
    at initStripePaymentIntent (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/dependencies/external-services/stripe.services.js:39:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async topupViaStripe (/home/haya/Project/FWZ-main-main/Fly With Zoki Back-End/api/controllers/topup.controllers.js:33:37)
 2023-07-27 15:41:55 | WARNING: Requested operation failed. Unknown Stripe SDK error. 
POST /topups/methods/stripe 500 1609.486 ms - 131
```

If you want any other things for me to show you for your help, Feel free to comment. A Solution will be so grateful. :)

Comment: It appears that the `req.params.walletId` in your `updateWalletId` function is the line throwing the error. Specifically, `req.params` is undefined.

Comment: Although While hitting that API it works fine. The error is in the stripe.services. Because while hitting that API it gives Stripe SDK error.

Comment: There's no Stripe SDK error. The `stripe.services.js` is only mentioned in the errors as it's in that file where you call `await updateWalletId`, which fails because of what I explained above. Are you passing any query parameters when you call your`/:walletId` endpoint which triggers `updateWalletId`? For example: `/wallet_id?foo=bar`.

Comment: No there is no endpoint there. I've removed that await before updateWalletById and the SDK error is gone but the other two errors:
1- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'walletId')
2- TypeError: res.status is not a function
Are just displaying in the terminal console